# Is it possible to aggregate expenses per category in google spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to track my expenses manually. I looked for already built options and I did not find anyone I knew how to use or that it covered what I want to do.

What I am doing is basically manually write down what appears in my bank, with the intention of categorizing the expenses myself, since as I said, I did not find a better way to do it.

So it looks like this:

```
Cinema | 11.95
Going out   (restaurant1) | 26.55
Netflix | 13.95
Weekly purchases | 72.66
Going out   | 9
Bill (type) | 29.16
Rent month | 650
Going out   | 26.55
Bill (type2) | 66.45
Compra semanal  | 81.09
Bill (type3)    | 21.1
```

( "|" is used as if it were two different cells) And what I would like now is to take the generic name that I gave the cathegory (without the parenthesis, I am using those for myself, so I can track where was the money spent, more specifically), and how much was spent.

In programming I would do this with a regex for the left cell, and aggregating by name, and then plotting the data somehow. I am unsure if this is even possible, maybe I should use Excel but Drive has the cloud advantage so I would like some help as to where to start, I do not need anything too fancy, **a new column with the category and the total spent would work wonders for me**, but I have not found an easy way of doing it (and I doubt I am doing something so complex, so I assume I am thinking this the wrong way). **Best case scenario, I manage to plot it all so it is more visual, or I can have several columns plotted against each other** (I have different columns for shared expenses, personal expenses, and so on).

Comment: Ideally I want anything I write before a parenthesis in the first cell to be a category. So, if I input Byll by mistake, that will appear as a category. Reason for this is I do not plan on having that many and I feel it might be easier. I do not know how to split from the parenthesis part AND aggregate by name AND then write it in some other cell or plot it. It's the sum of operations that leave me with little clue as to how should I proceed @pnuts

Comment: Wow! You need regex, aggregation ad then a plotted chart. Maybe you could get started with SUMIFS and COUNTIFS first and work from there?

Comment: No idea, I guess knowing the name of the function will help. What would be an easier way of doing it? Maybe putting the data in the parenthesis in another column would erase the problem of the regex... That might be one problem less? Thing is, I do not know how to approach the problem and I feel I am creating more problems that are needed for the task!!

Answer (score 1):

If you can put the category (e.g. Bill) in a separate column from your details (e.g. type 1) then the Pivot Table feature is exactly what you need.

Start with something like this (the heading on each column is important):

```
Category | Details | Amount
Cinema | | 11.95
Going out | restaurant 1 | 26.55
Netflix | | 13.95
Weekly purchases | | 72.66
Going out | | 9
Bill | type | 29.16
Rent month | | 650
Going out | | 26.55
Bill | type2 | 66.45
Compra semanal | | 81.09
Bill | type3 | 21.1
```

Then click Data, Pivot Table.  Under Rows, click Add and choose Category.  Under Values, click Add and choose Amount.  You should see a table like this:

```
Category | SUM of Amount
Bill| 116.71
Cinema | 11.95
Compra semanal | 81.09
Going out | 62.1
Netflix | 13.95
Rent month | 650
Weekly purchases | 72.66
Grand Total | 1008.46
```

Any unique value in the Category column creates a new row in the pivot table.

Further Details: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/1272900

Comment: Well that was great, I did not know it was possible to do that in that manner. Problem is, I am doing it wrong, since the categories do not add up properly. Any tips on what should I put on rows and what on columns? Like, I have 1 column describing the expense, another with the type, and a 3rd with the number. I am playing with the wizard but so far I do not get how to use it.

Comment: How would you add data from different columns as categories? I have found the way to plot data vs values but if I try more than one column, it tries to create a matrix and not a concatenated list

Comment: @monkeyintern I've edited the answer with more details.  I think you want to put the amount as a total value, not a set of columns, or you'll get a matrix.

Answer (score 1):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({REGEXREPLACE(TRIM(A:A)," \(.*\)",),B:B},"Select Col1,sum(Col2) where Col1 is not null group by Col1"))
```